# How to use Intel realsense camera's (ZR300) with pre-made video or image instead live capture

Tags: intel, video-capture, video-processing, realsense

I want to use pre-made files instead of live capture in the following program to track the person.

1. what is realsense SDK API used to load pre-made files and catch the frame by frame?
2. Is it possible to use to detect/track person any general video/image files which captured using any other camera's ?

Example Program:

[Example Source Link](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense_samples/blob/master/samples/or_pt_tutorial_1_web/cpp/main.cpp)

### Source

```
    #include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include "version.h"
#include "pt_utils.hpp"
#include "pt_console_display.hpp"
#include "pt_web_display.hpp"
#include "or_console_display.hpp"
#include "or_web_display.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace rs::core;
using namespace rs::object_recognition;

// Version number of the samples
extern constexpr auto rs_sample_version = concat("VERSION: ",RS_SAMPLE_VERSION_STR);

// Doing the OR processing for a frame can take longer than the frame interval, so we
// keep track of whether or not we are still processing the last frame.
bool is_or_processing_frame = false;
unique_ptr<web_display::pt_web_display> pt_web_view;
unique_ptr<web_display::or_web_display> or_web_view;

unique_ptr<console_display::pt_console_display> pt_console_view;
unique_ptr<console_display::or_console_display> or_console_view;

void processing_OR(correlated_sample_set or_sample_set, or_video_module_impl* impl, or_data_interface* or_data,
                   or_configuration_interface* or_configuration)
{
    rs::core::status st;

    // Declare data structure and size for results
    rs::object_recognition::localization_data* localization_data = nullptr;

    //Run object localization processing
    st = impl->process_sample_set(or_sample_set);
    if (st != rs::core::status_no_error)
    {
        is_or_processing_frame = false;
        return;
    }

    // Retrieve recognition data from the or_data object
    int array_size = 0;
    st = or_data->query_localization_result(&localization_data, array_size);
    if (st != rs::core::status_no_error)
    {
        is_or_processing_frame = false;
        return;
    }

    //Send OR data to ui
    if (localization_data && array_size != 0)
    {
        or_console_view->on_object_localization_data(localization_data, array_size, or_configuration);
        or_web_view->on_object_localization_data(localization_data, array_size, or_configuration);
    }

    is_or_processing_frame = false;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    rs::core::status st;
    pt_utils pt_utils;

    rs::core::image_info colorInfo,depthInfo;
    rs::core::video_module_interface::actual_module_config actualModuleConfig;
    rs::person_tracking::person_tracking_video_module_interface* ptModule = nullptr;
    rs::object_recognition::or_video_module_impl impl;
    rs::object_recognition::or_data_interface* or_data = nullptr;
    rs::object_recognition::or_configuration_interface* or_configuration = nullptr;

    cout << endl << "Initializing Camera, Object Recognition and Person Tracking modules" << endl;
    if(pt_utils.init_camera(colorInfo,depthInfo,actualModuleConfig,impl,&or_data,&or_configuration) != rs::core::status_no_error)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Device is null." << endl << "Please connect a RealSense device and restart the application" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    pt_utils.init_person_tracking(&ptModule);

    //Person Tracking Configuration. Set tracking mode to 0
    ptModule->QueryConfiguration()->QueryTracking()->Enable();
    ptModule->QueryConfiguration()->QueryTracking()->SetTrackingMode((Intel::RealSense::PersonTracking::PersonTrackingConfiguration::TrackingConfiguration::TrackingMode)0);
    if(ptModule->set_module_config(actualModuleConfig) != rs::core::status_no_error)
    {
        cerr<<"error : failed to set the enabled module configuration" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //Object Recognition Configuration
    //Set mode to localization
    or_configuration->set_recognition_mode(rs::object_recognition::recognition_mode::LOCALIZATION);
    //Set the localization mechnizm to use CNN
    or_configuration->set_localization_mechanism(rs::object_recognition::localization_mechanism::CNN);
    //Ignore all objects under 0.7 probabilty (confidence)
    or_configuration->set_recognition_confidence(0.7);
    //Enabling object center feature
    or_configuration->enable_object_center_estimation(true);

    st = or_configuration->apply_changes();
    if (st != rs::core::status_no_error)
        return st;

    //Launch GUI
    string sample_name = argv[0];
    // Create console view
    pt_console_view = move(console_display::make_console_pt_display());
    or_console_view = move(console_display::make_console_or_display());
    // Create and start remote(Web) view
    or_web_view = move(web_display::make_or_web_display(sample_name, 8000, true));
    pt_web_view = move(web_display::make_pt_web_display(sample_name, 8000, true));


    cout << endl << "-------- Press Esc key to exit --------" << endl << endl;

    while (!pt_utils.user_request_exit())
    {
        //Get next frame
        rs::core::correlated_sample_set* sample_set = pt_utils.get_sample_set(colorInfo,depthInfo);
        rs::core::correlated_sample_set* sample_set_pt = pt_utils.get_sample_set(colorInfo,depthInfo);

        //Increment reference count of images at sample set
        for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<uint8_t>(rs::core::stream_type::max); ++i)
        {
            if (sample_set_pt->images[i] != nullptr)
            {
                sample_set_pt->images[i]->add_ref();
            }
        }

        //Draw Color frames
        auto colorImage = (*sample_set)[rs::core::stream_type::color];
        pt_web_view->on_rgb_frame(10, colorImage->query_info().width, colorImage->query_info().height, colorImage->query_data());

        //Run OR in a separate thread. Update GUI with the result
        if (!is_or_processing_frame)         // If we aren't already processing or for a frame:
        {
            is_or_processing_frame = true;
            std::thread recognition_thread(processing_OR, *sample_set,
                                           &impl, or_data, or_configuration);
            recognition_thread.detach();
        }

        //Run Person Tracking
        if (ptModule->process_sample_set(*sample_set_pt) != rs::core::status_no_error)
        {
            cerr << "error : failed to process sample" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        //Update GUI with PT result
        pt_console_view->on_person_info_update(ptModule);
        pt_web_view->on_PT_tracking_update(ptModule);

    }

    pt_utils.stop_camera();
    actualModuleConfig.projection->release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any has example video recorded using realsense zr300 camera, please share the video.

Answer (score 0):

1. After installing the Realsense SKD, check the realsense_playback_device_sample for how to load the RSSDK capture file.
2. The short answer is not really. Beside the images that are captured from the other camera, you also need to supply the camera intrinsic and extrinsic settings in order to calculate the depth of and object and call the person tracking module.